# How to make scoped variable in Controller based on some condition in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code in Angularjs Controller is like :

```
$scope.validElements = [                                    
                                 {
                                    "id": "One",              
                                 }, 
                                 {
                                    "id": "Two",
                                 }, 
                                 {
                                    "id": "Three",
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "id": "Four",
                                 }
                            ];
```

How can i make validElements to be different based on condition 
`( if(someService.someElement == "ABC") )` then

```
$scope.validElements = [                                    
                                 {
                                    "id": "One",              
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "id": "Three",
                                 }    
                        ];
```

otherwise

```
$scope.validElements = [                                    
                                {
                                    "id": "One",              
                                 }, 
                                 {
                                    "id": "Two",
                                 }, 
                                 {
                                    "id": "Three",
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "id": "Four",
                                 }
                        ];
```

Please give suggestions if it is possible or any rough idea how it can be done

Comment: Do you want `$scope.validElements` to be bound to `someService.someElement`?

Comment: @WilliamGaul : Yes, i mean the condition is based on some element present in `someService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to create another scoped variable and set it equal to someService, and then place a watch on someSome element.  You can then handle the condition in the watch function.  I've done this to watch service variables

```
    $scope.validElements = [ // set default here               
         {
            "id": "One",              
         } // ...
    ];
    $scope.someService = someService;
    $scope.$watch('someService.someElement', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // or a switch statment
        if(newValue == 'ABC'){
            $scope.validElements = [                                    
                     {
                        "id": "One",              
                     },
                     {
                        "id": "Three",
                     }    
            ];
        }else{
            // handle else condition
            $scope.validElements = [                                    
                    {
                        "id": "One",              
                     }, 
                     {
                        "id": "Two",
                     }, 
                     {
                        "id": "Three",
                     },
                     {
                        "id": "Four",
                     }
            ];
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps! good luck

Comment: I will try to implement with this & will let you know. Thanks for the prompt reply. :)